# Notification button not work with some Android devices

Tags: android, button, service, notifications, android-notifications

I have weird problem. I was implemented notification with action buttons, which perfectly works on Adroid 5.0, but not on Android 4.2 or higher (whathever 4.0 android). I can see buttons, I can click on buttons, but nothing happens. Global notification intent is working fine on both version, only action buttons are not :/ Can someone give me advise how it is possible ??

Here's my code:

```
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    switch (intent.getAction()) {
        case ServiceUtils.ACTION_SERVICE_START_FOREGROUND:
            ...
            if (object != null) {
                buildNotification();
                ...
            }
            break;
        case ServiceUtils.ACTION_SERVICE_PAUSE_FOREGROUND:
            ...
            if (object != null) {
                ...
                buildNotification();
            }
            break;
        case ServiceUtils.ACTION_SERVICE_STOP_FOREGROUND:
            // stop service
            ...
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();

            // dismiss notification from bar
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.cancel(...);
            break;
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

private void buildNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(...)
            .setTicker(getString(R.string.service_begin))
            .setContentText(...)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_join)
            .setLargeIcon(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_menu_join), 128, 128, false))
            .setContentIntent(getNotificationIntent())
            .setOngoing(true)
            .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel, getString(R.string.service_notification_stop), getStopIntent());

    if (condition) {
        notification.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause, getString(R.string.service_notification_pause), getPauseIntent());
    }

    startForeground(..._FOREGROUND_SERVICE, notification.build());
}

// GET INTENTS
private PendingIntent getStopIntent() {
    Intent stopIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
    stopIntent.setAction(ServiceUtils.ACTION_SERVICE_STOP_FOREGROUND);
    stopIntent.putExtra(..., ...);
    return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, stopIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

private PendingIntent getPauseIntent() {
    Intent pauseIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
    pauseIntent.setAction(ServiceUtils.ACTION_SERVICE_PAUSE_FOREGROUND);
    pauseIntent.putExtra(..., ...);
    pauseIntent.putExtra(..., ...);
    return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, pauseIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

private PendingIntent getNotificationIntent() {
    Intent notificationIntent;
    if (condition) {
        notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ...class);
    } else {
        notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ...class);
    }

    notificationIntent.putExtra(..., ...);
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

Problem with Android 4.0 is like after clicking on notification buttons, nothing happens, neither start that "intent" ?? I had logs there and nothing ... :/ On some devices are working, on some not

Comment: Try temporarily raising the `Notification` yourself with `NotificationManager`, rather than use `startForeground()`, and see if the custom actions work. If they do, then the problem may be in the combination of `NotificationCompat` and `startForeground()`. BTW, AFAIK, the proper way to get rid of your `startForeground()` `Notification` is `stopForeground()`.